# Modal dismiss not working after load function

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I´ve been looking for a solution but nothing seems to be solving this.

I have a modal load function script in my code and the modal it is displaying OK, but when i try to close the modal from a data-dismiss="modal" instruction using one of the html buttons in the code, it doens'nt close the modal but if i click on the "open Modal" button then the two close buttons work OK:

```js
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
$(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
},3000);
</script>
```

```html
<div class="container"><!-- Trigger the modal with a button --> <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button> <!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog"><!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Some text in the modal.</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

So data-dismiss="modal" only works when I load the modal manually from the "Open Modal" button but it does not work when I use the load function to display it on page load.

I'll appreciate any help and any suggestions will be welcome,

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    },3000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container"><!-- Trigger the modal with a button --> <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button> <!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog"><!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Some text in the modal.</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello SaJed, thanks for your help, i've test the script that you sent me, but still is not working, do you think that I should instance the close button somehow in the script? because it seems not to be linked to the modal when it loads with the load function but works flawless when it loads with the trigger button.

Comment: I have test the snippet and it works i even test it on brackets, it loads ok but i think it is not working in my Environment because i am restricted to use an html editor that doesn't alow me to use body or head tag's to embed css stylesheets so it loads the modal no matter what, i have to use the Style display:none to hice the modal on load, but now when i click the load button it seems to load ok, but is not showing the background image of the modal-dialog class.